# Using fread as read.csv

Tags: r, data.table

I am a beginner in R, and recently came across `data.table` package. When I started learning R, I didn't know that `data.table` is faster and preserves the column name. i.e. Product Revenue wouldn't be read as "Product.Revenue," So, I wrote a lot of code using "dot" in column names. Now, if I want to switch to data.table, I'm unsure how to change the column name from "spaced" version such as "Product Revenue" to "dotted" version such as "Product.Revenue"

Here's a sample `.csv` file I created for illustration:

```
Product Type,Marginal Revenue,Marginal Cost,Marginal profit
1,2,3.4,3
```

Here's the output from `read.csv`:

```
read.csv("test.csv")
  Product.Type Marginal.Revenue Marginal.Cost Marginal.profit
    1                2           3.4               3
```

Here's the output from fread:

```
data.table::fread("test.csv",stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
   Product Type Marginal Revenue Marginal Cost Marginal profit
          1                2           3.4               3
```

Now, I don't want to change all the code I have written. Is there anyway I can use fread to read the data and then change the column names similar to `read.csv()`? This way, later part of my code will be compatible. I'd appreciate any thoughts.

I did search for this topic on SO, and didn't find any thread. I found a bunch of threads on leading and lagging spaces, such as [fread from data.table package when column names include spaces and special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966957/fread-from-data-table-package-when-column-names-include-spaces-and-special-chara) , but not at all relating to what I want. I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: `read.table(..., check.names = FALSE)` will not mangle names either.

Comment: `names(dt) <- gsub(" ", ".", names(dt))`

Comment: Your "sample .csv" is notably lacking in commas separating its values.

Comment: @Frank --This was output from Excel's view saved as CSV. Here's my actual csv file. Product Type,Marginal Revenue,Marginal Cost,Marginal profit...then on new line, I have: 
1,2,3.4,3

Comment: add `check.names=TRUE` to your `fread` call. I think you''ll need the development version on GH though